Solid Torus as a CW complex
We know that $\mathbb{S}^1×\mathbb{D}^2$ give a solid torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
As product of two CW complexes give another CW complex.  Therefore Solid Torus is a CW complex.
How to give CW complex structure on $\mathbb{S}^1×\mathbb{D}^2$ ?
If we take CW structure on a circle with one $0-$ cell and one $1-$ cell and take CW structure on $D^2$ with one $0-$cell ,one $1$ cell and one $2$ cell .
Then their product should have one $0$ cell , two $1$ cells , two $2$ cells and one $3$ cell. But how to attach the cells to get solid torus .

Hint: can you make a CW complex structure on a solid cylinder? How do you think that would help with a solid torus? Independent hint: presumably the proof of the theorem you cite about the product of CW complexes is constructive?

Do you know the proof that a product of two CW complexes gives another CW complex? If you do, then you give a CW structure yourself, starting from your favorite CW structures on $\mathbb S^1$ and $\mathbb D^2$.
